# Problem with Jacobian criterion and regular local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Take $X=\operatorname{Spec}(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^p+t))$ with $k=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $p\neq2$.

The Jacobian ideal is $J=(y,y^2-x^p+t)=(y,x^p-t)$ which is maximal ie a closed point of $X$ so Jacobian criterion work to say that $\mathfrak{p}=(y,x^p-t)$ is singular.

Let's $A=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^p+t)$ then in $A_\mathfrak{p}$ one have $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}=(y)$ because $x^p-t=y^2\in(y)$ so $\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}$ has so many generator as $\dim A_\mathfrak{p}$ (which is 1 because $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal in $A$ so $\dim A=\dim A_\mathfrak{p}$). So $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is regular ie $\mathfrak{p}$ is regular.

Where is my stupid mistake?

Comment: Why is that the Jacobian ideal?

Comment: Jacobian criterion gives you smooth points (over the base field), not regular points. For example, with $k$ as in your question and $L=\mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})$, $L$ is a field and thus regular, but the extension $k\subset L$ is not smooth and the Jacobian ideal is zero.

Comment: Ok I think I see my mistake: I use theorem 2.16 in Liu's book (page 130) which is a Jacobian criterion for regularity but for $k$-rationnal points. Here my point is closed but not rationnal so the theorem doesn't applied. Why it work for rationnals but not for only closed points?... I should study the proof! Thanks a lot

Comment: @user113102: the ideal form with formal derivative of the equation + the equation itself, so the derivatives are null in $A/\mathfrak{m}$ iff $J\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$

Comment: Ah ok thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that, as **Mohan** pointed out, the Jacobian criterion checks whether $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is $\underline{\text{smooth}}$. The notion of regularity is related, but not identical.

In fact, we have the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be a finite type $k$-scheme. Then, the following are equivalent
>
> 1. $X$ is smooth over $k$.
> 2. $X_{\overline{k}}$ is regular.
> 3. $X_{k^\mathrm{perf}}$ is regular (where $k^\mathrm{perf}$ is the perfect closure of $k$ in some fixed algebraic closure of $k$).
> 4. $X_{k'}$ is regular for all finite extensions $k'/k$.
> 5. $X_{k'}$ is regular for all extensions $k'/k$.

In particular, if $k$ is perfect then $X$ is smooth over $k$ if and only if its regular. The necessity that $X_{k^\mathrm{perf}}$ is illustrated by your example and, in fact, is even the example they give on The Stacks Project to highlight this issue (see [Tag038Y](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/038Y)). In fact, you can check that for your $X$ you even that $X_{k^\mathrm{sep}}$ is regular!